# Sorting rows by time in .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, time

I'm a begginer in programming and I decided to learn it by trying to code a programme in Python 3.8.. The progress is slow, but helpfully I've found a lot of answers on this site, so I'm moving forward. However I've found a problem that I can't found an answer, so I hope someone can help me. 
My programm is intendent to store result from track in athletics. User input results into empty file and then it get sorted in a way that the best result in some discipline is displayed first and then teh second best is second ... Beside the time, input requires date and place. So the final output in .txt file looks like:

> 100m #the discipline
>
> 1. 9;99 01.01.2019 London #delimiter is \t
> 2. 10;00 02.01.2019 New York
>
> Halfmarathon #second discipline
>
> 1. 59:59;99 21.09.2019 Berlin
> 2. 1:00:00;01 23.04.2019 Boston

Time format is hours:minutes:second;hunderth of the second and if hours and minutes are 0, they aren't displayed (like in 100m or hours in Halfmarathon).

Now I'm working on upgrading the program; I'm trying to insert results into already written file. So, let's say the athlete run excatly 1 h on halfmarathon today and I want to insert that result into the file to like like this:

> 100m #the discipline
>
> 1. 9;99 01.01.2019 London #delimiter is \t
> 2. 10;00 02.01.2019 New York
>
> Halfmarathon #second discipline
>
> 1. 59:59;99 21.09.2019 Berlin
> 2. 1:00:00;00 21.11.2019 StackOverflow
> 3. 1:00:00;01 23.04.2019 Boston

So I need to insert the result into 2. place in halfmarathon discipline. I know how to find the correct discipline (so halfmarathon) and how to display all the results in the discipline, but I have no idea how to extract results, input new results and then sort them all.

So to conclude I need some general idea for this problem, not the exact code. This is my code for now:

```
    import csv

with open('test.txt', 'r+') as csv_file:
    csv_reader =csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')

    a = '600 m' #discipline
    found = False #searching if our discipline is in the file
    for line in csv_reader:
        if line == [a]:
            found = True
            for line in csv_reader:
                lenght = len(line)
                if lenght < 4: #result have lenght of 4 (place, result, date, location), when lenght is shorter, that means that there are no more results in this dsicipline
                    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
                    input = input('Input something: ') #trying to write something to the last line of this discipline, I was trying to see if this works
                    csv_writer.writerow([vnos])
                    break #break
                else:
                    print(line) # printing the results
```